# REST API to access the Google Photos shared album without account login

Tags: android, rest, google-photos

I am writing an Android application to view the shared (public) albums from Google Photos without Signing to Google account(authentication). Is there any Google Photos REST API available for this requirement? Kindly throw some light.

Comment: have you figured it out? I'm trying to achieve the same thing and I'm kinda getting pissed of over the google photos API

Answer (score 8):

Here is some light:

https://kunnas.com/google-photos-is-a-disaster/

but it is still darkness from the Google side

Comment: plus 1 for the funny answer :D